# Question regarding register_nav_menus();

Tags: menus

I got below code in TwentyFourteen theme's function.php file.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary'   => __( 'Top primary menu', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary menu in left sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    ) );
```

I would like to know about `twentyfourteen`. I know this is description from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu).

Where is this text display in WordPress ?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct, You would like to know about where `Top primary menu` is written.

So **answer is simple**, it is the part of the **back end**.You need to `login` to your **admin dashboard**.

After `login` , Go to `Appearance > Menus`. When you go here, you will find below **screen**:

[image]

In **above** pic, you can find `Menu Name`. Here you need to **create Menu first**. Give any name. I have given **My Menu**.

[image]

After giving any name, you can see `Create Menu` button. **Hit** that button to **create Menu**. So now will see following screen.

[image]

As you can see in above picture, there is **two tab** now.Second tab is `Manage Locations`. When you click on that tab, you will see **above to text**.See below picture:

[image]

So basically, these name is for the **locations of the menu** where you can decide which menu should appear in which location.

Comment: Thanks @Rohil_PHPBeginner for your reply. But I would like to know "Where is the text `twentyfourteen` display in WordPress ?"

Comment: Its not for the `front end`. So you can not see it in front end.

Comment: I would like to see at `back end` (admin dashboard).

Comment: I am wondering why do you want it at back end and for what purpose ?

Comment: Actually I would like to know that function properly.

Comment: Its a function that is wrapped around your mentioned code.So suppose if you have `function foysal_setup()` then above code would be something like this : `register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary'   => __( 'Top primary menu', 'foysal' ),
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary menu in left sidebar', 'foysal' ),
    ) );`.

So you can not see that anywhere neither on back end nor front end.Its part of programming.

Comment: May be it's just a signature to mark a menu.

Comment: May be in simple words for understanding purpose. But it should be same as your function.

Answer (score 0):

twentyfourteen is the text domain for the theme, which is used for defining all string in the theme, that are translatable. Secon parameter of functions _e() and __() are the text domain for the specific theme or plugin.

More on text domains (and localization as a general topic) you can read here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Text_Domains